# Анимация в css через keyframes

Tags: html, css, css-animation

Надо анимировать задание, а у меня, включая локально, даже отрывок не работает. Пробовала писать просто и через префиксы

```
<div class="smoke">
                <div class="smoke-1"></div>
                <div class="smoke-2"></div>
                <div class="smoke-3"></div>
            </div>
```

Css

```
 .smoke-1 {
        top: -25px;
        right: 44px;
        -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;

        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    }

    @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
        0%, 25%  {
            -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);

        }

        35%, 100% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);

        }
    }


    .smoke-2 {
        top: -25px;
        right: 42px;
    }

    .smoke-3 {
        top: -25px;
        right: 49px;
    }
```

Файл подключен правильно. При обновлении в браузере ничего не происходит

Comment: а что не так? если добавить контент или размер, то работает https://jsfiddle.net/zhacb4gf/

Comment: да, я тоже проверила. Но не могу понять почему у меня в браузере не работает ( В своем ide все же удобнее работать

Comment: если у вас это не работает только при открытии вашей страницы, но работает на сайте, то скорее всего вы что-то подключили не правильно (т.к. на сайте тот же css, только запущенный в iframe), если подключали как отдельный файл, проверьте консоль/network, попробуйте убрать файл и использовать <style>

Comment: подключала через link, сам css нормально отображается (т.е. все элементы со всеми цветами), только анимация не работает. Через style не получилось

Comment: и обычно, если используют префиксы, то их объявляют вместе с обычными свойствами, например `animation-name: ....; -webkit-animation-name: ...;`

Comment: впервые с ними работаю) Онлайн создатель префиксов тоже так показал, но с ними так не работало все равно. А потом в инете увидела, что все примеры просто с префиксами без обычных свойств, поэтому убрала. Буду знать!

Comment: а что должно произойти в анимации ?

Comment: конкретно в данном случае посередине круг уменьшается и увеличивается) А так там нужно целый набор анимации, поэтому не хотела все делать в онлайн

Comment: там не сложно ..если опишите конкретно что должно быть и как я сделаю но ни здесь а у Вас на компе